# Get more insights about LCP and CWV stats from Google page Insights?

Tags: seo, core-web-vitals, google-insights

When I look at LCP stats below on google page insights, I see 34% request are in green, 30% in orange, and 35% in red.

[image]

I want to further deep dive into it how some requests are in good range and some in bad. Can I get to know from Google Search Console or some other tool what kind of devices and internet bandwidth people in green/orange/red are using as my back end response time is same consistently for last 2 months? Is there way I can get these insights so that understand the RCA here and take the corrective action?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [CrUX Dashboard](https://web.dev/chrome-ux-report-data-studio-dashboard/) can show you historical data for your origin-level performance. It's based on the Chrome UX Report (CrUX) dataset, which is also what PageSpeed Insights uses. The dashboard includes coarse distributions of [user demographics](https://web.dev/chrome-ux-report-data-studio-dashboard/#user-demographics) like effective connection types and device form factors.

For finer-grained insights about which types of users are experiencing slow performance, you can use the [public CrUX dataset](https://web.dev/chrome-ux-report-bigquery/) on BigQuery. There are some sample queries in the [CrUX Cookbook](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/CrUX/tree/main/sql) repository. For example, you can look up the 75th percentile LCP value for 4G mobile users in the US:

```sql
SELECT
  `chrome-ux-report`.experimental.PERCENTILE(ARRAY_AGG(bin), 75) AS p75_lcp
FROM
  `chrome-ux-report.experimental.country`,
  UNNEST(largest_contentful_paint.histogram.bin) AS bin
WHERE
  yyyymm = 202001 AND
  country_code = 'us' AND
  origin = 'https://www.example.com' AND
  effective_connection_type.name = '4G' AND
  form_factor.name != 'desktop'
```

[Source](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/CrUX/blob/main/sql/test-my-site.sql)

Using these tools you should have a better understanding of the user demographics on your site and how they correlate to performance.

Comment: Thanks! Will explore it.Looks like we can definitely get the connection type.  Can we also get the details like exact device (like model) with in the mobile device type or memory/cpu info ?

Comment: The dataset only contains coarse device info like desktop, phone, or tablet. For more granular data, you'd need to use an analytics tool.